# How to pass message property dynamically to alert controller subTitle property?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

**.ts**

```
//imported everything


@Component({
    selector: 'anything',
    templateUrl: '.html',

})

export class anything{

public x: number;
let message : string;


    constructor(public nav: NavController, public authData: AuthData,public service: Service) { }


   async doSomething() {

       try {

       await this.authData.Something(this.x); 

}
catch(error){
this.message = 'Sorry, sme error occured'

this.service.showAlert();

}            
    }
```

**service.ts**

```
//using alert controller code in this class.

showAlert(){
title: 'static',
subtitle: '',  // need to add this message dynamically from the function that called the showAlert() function.

button: [Okay];
}
//code implemented.
```

Assuming that **.ts** class when calls the doSomething() and it throws exception which is caught in the catch block and the catch block triggers the alert Controller's showAlert() function,

**Question**: How do I dynamically place the value of subTitle in the showAlert() so that I can send the message according to the function called?

**Note**: please ignore the syntax errors and typos and imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. You need to pass parameters to you calling function**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'anything',
    templateUrl: '.html',

})

export class anything{

public x: number;
let message : string;


constructor(public nav: NavController, public authData: AuthData,public service: Service) { }


async doSomething() {
       try { 
       await this.authData.Something(this.x);  
         }

catch(error){
this.message = 'Sorry, sme error occured'
//Add message as args to the calling method
this.service.showAlert(this.message); 

 }            
}
```

**2. You would also need to let the method in your service know you're passing it arguments like so.**

```
//Receive args in service.Good idea to type
showAlert(receivedMessage:string){
title: 'static',
subtitle: receivedMessage,  // Add received message to alert body

button: [Okay];
}
```